# A "scientific" word for probably

Tags: word-choice, science

Given a particular idea, is there any scientific word, or an elegant way to describe in once sentence, that I am pretty sure there is no method *not* based on this particular idea? For example, when writing a scientific paper, I am pretty sure I read every paper on the topic, and there is no mention of any other idea for a method, how would I then write:

> All methods to date are *probably* based on idea xyz.

or

> *To the best of knowledge*, all methods to date are based on idea xyz.

I find above sentences to sound like I didn't have the motivation to search long enough or just didn't care.

Comment: "Our search revealed no ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two often used expressions are

> We are not aware of any method...
>
> All existing methods seem to be based

which leave room for error on your side but convey the message.

The expression

> To (the best of) our knowledge

mentioned in other answers is also fine.

Comment: I like "We are not aware of any method...". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> To the best of our knowledge...

I think this one is "scientific" enough. It has been used by my advisor (whose language choice I trust) and it hints that you did your best to study the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word, but it supports your confidence in your claim:

> My exhaustive search suggests that every method to date is based on idea xyz.

And perhaps add a footnote explaining the scope of "exhaustive."

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid I'm not particularly good at English, but this is what I was taught about writing an introductory part of a scientific paper.

> I am pretty sure there is no method not based on this particular idea

Since you can never prove the uniqueness of your idea XYZ (there might have been a group of scientists in USSR who already published the same idea to Russian journals in '60s,) you can only go as far as:

> Although major effort has been put into PQR[1-3] and STU[4-7], they are all based on XYZ[8-9] and share the common drawback of JKL[10, 11].  To overcome the JKL problem, here we propose a novel approach FastABC ...

After all, the uniqueness of your idea alone isn't enough for a good scientific research...